# AvalonDock loads different theme (dll) on different pc

Tags: wpf, avalondock, xceed

I have figured out that AvalonDock loads different theme depending on different windows color scheme. For example if I am using windows server 2003 with classic theme then it looks for 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.classic.dll'. If I am using windows 7 then it looks for 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Aero.dll'. And for windows 8 it looks for 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Aero2.dll'

I need to add all themes to my application folder so that it works on different version of Windows. I don't want this. I want only one theme dll in application directory. I set Theme of DockingManager to some theme (Aero), but still AvalonDock tries to load classic dll which is not present in application folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm specifying the theme like this in my application and never had any issues:

```
<DockingManager Name="dockingManager">
    <DockingManager.Theme>
        <VS2010Theme/>
    </DockingManager.Theme>
    <LayoutRoot>
        <LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <LayoutDocumentPane/>
            </LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </LayoutPanel>
    </LayoutRoot>
</DockingManager>
```